# Django Wagtail elastic search 2.4 ascii folding

Tags: django, python-3.x, elasticsearch, wagtail

Is it possible to set ascii folding on Wagtail elasticsearch 2.4 search backend so that e.g. searching for "Nimes" returns objects with "Nîmes" indexed?

I tried adding the following settings:

```
WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'app.search.backend',
        'URLS': ['http://search:9200'],
        'INDEX': 'wagtail',
        'TIMEOUT': 5,
        'INDEX_SETTINGS': {
            'settings': {
                'analysis': {
                    'analyzer': {
                        'ngram_analyzer': {
                            'type': 'custom',
                            'tokenizer': 'lowercase',
                            'filter': ['asciifolding', 'ngram']
                        },
                        'edgengram_analyzer': {
                            'type': 'custom',
                            'tokenizer': 'lowercase',
                            'filter': ['asciifolding', 'edgengram']
                        },
                        "folding": {
                            "tokenizer": "standard",
                            "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.
I'm using Wagtail 1.9 on Django 1.10.7 with Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `app.search.backend` is inheriting from `Elasticsearch2SearchBackend`? If so the default settings for the ES search backends in wagtail 1.9 already do ASCII folding. [See relevant code in wagtail](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/e0538ac311e1c7686b85b7189ac5ba0c62ccfa0c/wagtail/wagtailsearch/backends/elasticsearch.py#L686).

Comment: It is but even without changing anything in settings it doesn't seem to perform ASCII folding. Do I need to enable it in some other way?